# Виды опций "AccelMethod" в xorg.conf

Tags: linux, xorg

Подскажите какие опции есть для AccelMethod в файле xorg.conf, сейчас стоит опция CPU, только я не понимаю зачем она.

Comment: Зависит от видеокарты

Comment: а ещё похоже на ошибочное значение, которое скорей всего просто игнорируется — посмотри логи...

Comment: У меня Debian на планшета стоит, и там по стандарту CPU выставлено, если я не ошибаюсь, то там mali400